# How to connect to MySQL when using FastCGI for PHP under Apache on Windows Vista

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, fastcgi

I configured PHP to use Apache mod_fcgid. PHP is working, but after changes in configuration I am not able to connect to MySQL via PHP.
How to fix this?

To check MySQL connection I use the following PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password_here');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect. Error message: <' . mysql_error() . '>');
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

Error message returned by `mysql_error()` is empty.

I use the following configuration in Apache:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
<IfModule fcgid_module>  
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi .php  
DefaultInitEnv PHPRC "C:/Program Files/php5"
DefaultInitEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS      1000  
MaxRequestsPerProcess       1000  
MaxProcessCount 15
IPCCommTimeout 120
IdleTimeout 120
FCGIWrapper "C:/PROGRA~1/php5/php-cgi.exe" .php  
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php  

DefaultInitEnv PATH "C:/PROGRA~1/MYSQL/MYSQLS~1.0/LIB/OPT;C:/PROGRA~1/APACHE~1/APACHE2.2/BIN;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS"
</IfModule>
```

PHP 5.3.1, Apache/2.2.14 (Win32), MySQL 5.0.67-community-nt, Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 1. I downloaded binaries of mod_fcgid from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/mods/mod_fcgid-2.2b-w32.zip

**EDIT:**

I used `phpinfo()` to compare configuration. "`Loaded Configuration File`" is the same for both with and without `mod_fcgid`. `mysql` section is the same for both configs. What I found out that Environment section when mod_fcgid is turned on contains only FastCGI related variable (4 items only), while without mod_fcgid - much more.

**EDIT:**

I obtain the following warning:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: in E:\ ... \testphp\mysql.php on line 7

**EDIT**

Error log of mysql contain no any errors on `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: It could be a problem with MySQL itself try switching back from fastcgi to see if it works.

Comment: @DCC it works if I switch back.

Comment: do a error_reporting(E_ALL); before the lines you posted and see if ANYTHING is in the error log.

Comment: @DCC I obtain warning "Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: in E:\ ... \testphp\mysql.php on line 7", I updated the question. Can't realize what to do with this

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: in E:\ ... \testphp\mysql.php on line 7`
 is the full error ? Because that's unusual it should say what's wrong there.
Also please check your mysql server's log file for any anomalies and post them here. [mysql error log documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html)

Comment: Yes, this is a full log when page executed, and that is why it is so difficult for me to realize how to fix.
Concerning mysql logs: no any errors on mysql_connect().

Offtop: I just installed apache module - it works. But FastCGI is much better for me because I also have bugzilla installed which uses perl

Comment: Concerning php log. I have error_log = C:/temp/php_errors.log in php.ini, but file is not created, I see error messages as output on the page parsed by php.

Comment: Ok, completely uninstall Mysql and install again OR try to delete all logfiles from mysql (shutdown mysqld-nt, delete logfiles and start).
If that doesn't work try and upload to pastebin.org the php errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `php_info()` to see if the mysql module is present and configured for your CGI? The `ini` configuration can be different between CGI and other method of launching.

Comment: I added "EDIT" in post, which describes the answer

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and solved it this way:

1. Edit your php.ini file of cgi version (vi /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini)
2. Add the following line: extension=mysql.so
3. Restart your Apache (`service apache2 reload` AND `/etc/init.d/apache3 restart`)